# YouTube account authentication nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-data-api, service-accounts

I am making an application that searches for YouTube videos, and creates a playlist with those videos.

I've figured how to search for videos just using the API key provided, but am completely lost on how to do stuff as a user. At first, I thought that I could just use a service account to host all of the playlist, but I've learned quickly that YouTube doesn't support that.

My ultimate goal is to just create a playlist on my personal YouTube account, so I want that account to be hardcoded in.

I am struggling on changing it from using a service account to my personal account. Many other solutions I've seen use an express server with a frontend component, neither of which I have.

```
  import { google } from 'googleapis';
  import fs from 'fs';

  const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('config.json', 'utf8'));

  const key = require('./credentials.json');

  const scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube";

  const jwt = new google.auth.JWT(key.client_email, null, key.private_key, scopes);

  jwt.authorize((err, response) => {

     const yt = google.youtube({
        version: 'v3',
        auth: jwt,
     });

     yt.search.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        q: 'study music | zen music -livestream -live',
        maxResults: 1,
     }, (err, data) => {

        if (err) console.error(err);

        if (data) {

           console.log(data.data.items);
           // TODO: create playlist with these items

        }

     });

  });
```

Currently, it's using a service account to search for videos. I haven't done the playlist creation part yet because it would just keep giving an error as I'm using a service account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube API does not support service accounts. You will need to use Oauth2 and save the refresh token.  You can then use your refresh token to request a new access token whenever you need.

I recommend following [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/quickstart/nodejs)

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;

// If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
// at ~/.credentials/youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json
var SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly'];
var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'youtube-nodejs-quickstart.json';

// Load client secrets from a local file.
fs.readFile('client_secret.json', function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
    return;
  }
  // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the YouTube API.
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), getChannel);
});

/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 *
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
  var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
  var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function(err, token) {
    if (err) {
      getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    }
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oauth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback to call with the authorized
 *     client.
 */
function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
  var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
  var rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function(code) {
    rl.close();
    oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, token) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
        return;
      }
      oauth2Client.credentials = token;
      storeToken(token);
      callback(oauth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Store token to disk be used in later program executions.
 *
 * @param {Object} token The token to store to disk.
 */
function storeToken(token) {
  try {
    fs.mkdirSync(TOKEN_DIR);
  } catch (err) {
    if (err.code != 'EEXIST') {
      throw err;
    }
  }
  fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
  });
  console.log('Token stored to ' + TOKEN_PATH);
}

/**
 * Lists the names and IDs of up to 10 files.
 *
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function getChannel(auth) {
  var service = google.youtube('v3');
  service.channels.list({
    auth: auth,
    part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
    forUsername: 'GoogleDevelopers'
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
      return;
    }
    var channels = response.data.items;
    if (channels.length == 0) {
      console.log('No channel found.');
    } else {
      console.log('This channel\'s ID is %s. Its title is \'%s\', and ' +
                  'it has %s views.',
                  channels[0].id,
                  channels[0].snippet.title,
                  channels[0].statistics.viewCount);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What is the token that I am supposed to get back in the redirect url? After going through this flow and hosting a simple localhost node server for the redirect url to redirect back to, the url looks like: `http://<MY_REDIRECT_URL>?code=<SOME_CODE>&scope=<SCOPES>`.

Do I just paste the `SOME_CODE` part in the command line? The `SOME_CODE `and `SCOPES` part, or the entire url?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Youtube data api sucks hard. Most convoluted thing I've ever seen, with terrible docs and very poor response rate from google engineers, but at last I think I got it to work. I'll post an answer on one of these youtube api questions for the ultimate "how-to use youtube api with both api keys and oauth" guide I can possibly muster.

Comment: One question, does the offline refresh token ever expire? Or will it continue to refresh access_tokens when they expire without user intervention forever?

Comment: If your app is in the testing phase then the refresh token will expire after seven days.  Once you have set it to production it will not expire.  As long as you use it once ever six months.